# What compounds given can oxidize Mn(2+) to MnO4(-)?

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, redox, transition-metals

> $$\ce{Mn^2+ Solution ->[reagent 'A'] MnO4^-}$$
> The reagent '$\ce{A}$' can be
> (A) $\ce{Pb2O3 + \text{conc.} HNO3}$
> (B) $\ce{K2S2O8}$.
> (C) $\ce{(NH4)2S2O8}$
> (D) $\ce{K2SO4}$

All of the options can be reduced to their corresponding compounds so, Maybe all of them should be the answer. But the answer given is (A), (B), (C). Why is (D) not the answer? $\ce{SO4^2-}$ Can be reduced to $\ce{SO2}$ right?

Comment: D can be reduced, but you would need **much** stronger reducing agens than $\ce{Mn^2+}$ . And even if SO2 had been created somehow, it would be immmediately oxidized by $\ce{MnO4-}$.

Comment: **Everything** can be reduced. That's not what the question asks, though.

Comment: On Chemistry mathematical and chemical expressions can be formatted using MathJax (and LaTeX Syntax).  If you want to know more, please have a look [here](http://meta.chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/86/4945) and [here](http://meta.chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/443/4945). We prefer to not use MathJax in the title field, see [here](http://meta.chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/149/4945) for details.

Comment: $\ce{Pb2O3}$ does not exist. It should be replaced by $\ce{Pb3O4}$ which a useful substance for protecting iron pieces against rust.

Comment: @Maurice Hmm, without external reference, but: [Less common lead oxides](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lead_oxide) are:   Lead(II,IV) oxide, Pb2O3, lead sesquioxide (reddish yellow),     Pb12O19 (monoclinic, dark-brown or black crystals)

Comment: @Maurice https://pubs.rsc.org/en/content/articlelanding/1922/ct/ct9222101456#!divAbstract

Comment: @Safdar It seems to me MnO4^2- in the title may be an error, as in the body is listed MnO4-. Also, Mn^2+ needs acidic ( or at the best about neutral )pH, while MnO4^2- needs strongly alkaline pH. I am not aware of any alkaline path to produce MnO4- ( bot not saying it does not exist ).

Comment: It is not possible to create the manganate ion $\ce{MnO4^{2-}}$ from Mn(II) in basic medium with any reagent as presented in the question,

Comment: Pb2O3 is less known than some others, but is among several lead oxides listed in [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lead_oxide).

Comment: My bad, the question indeed asks for MnO4(-) :((

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the [standard electrode potentials](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_electrode_potential_(data_page)) answers your question (Note that conc. $\ce{HNO3}$ oxidizes $\ce{Pb2O3}$ to $\ce{PbO2}$) :
$$\begin{align}
\ce{PbO2 + 4H+ + 2e- &-> Pb^2+ + 2H2O } & E^0 = \pu{1.46 V} \\
\ce{S2O8^2- + 2e- &-> 2SO4- } & E^0 = \pu{2.01 V} \\
\ce{SO4^2- + 4H+ + 2e- &-> SO2 + 2H2O } & E^0 = \pu{0.17 V}
\end{align}$$

I couldn't find a reference for the couple $\ce{MnO4^2- | Mn^2+}$, but I'm guessing it would be slightly less than that of $\ce{MnO4- | Mn^2+}$, which is $\pu{1.51 V}$ (seeing that $\ce{PbO2}$ oxidizes it).

The standard electrode potential for the reduction of sulphur is less than that required to oxidize $\ce{Mn^2+}$, and hence the reaction does not proceed in the forward direction (net potential of cell is negative, which means that $\Delta G$ would be positive and cell reaction would be non-spontaneous)